# How to convert a png file to wsq within python?

Tags: python, nist

I am currently trying to convert fingerprint pngs to wsq so I can use them within NIST however, I haven't been able to do this. I have been attempting this myself within python so if any experience python users can help, it would be much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: what have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have tried manipulating ones which convert pngs to jpgs, and pngs to tiffs. I am able to convert more standard files but when i try to change the output to wsq, I get errors. I can’t find much information on the wsq library for python so I don’t know what additional information I need. When I try to look anything up, it just sends me to WSQ courses which cost over $500.

Comment: did you already install the [wsq library](https://pypi.org/project/wsq/)? seems pretty straightforward to me unless you're having problems installing it..

Comment: I actually sorted it. The issue was that I needed to convert the image to grayscale.